# Python3 multiply and add in a list.

Tags: list, python-3.x, addition, multiplication

got stuck in a exercise and could need som help!

> Exercise:  Create a function that takes the list:
>
> > [123, 4, 125, 69, 155]
>
> as argument. The function should multiply all even numbers by 1 and
>   add 6 to all odd numbers. Answer with the modified list sorted in
>   numerical order, descending.

my code so far is.

```
list1 = [123, 4, 125, 69, 155]

def multi():
    for num in list1:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            num * 1
        else:
            num + 6
        return list1
```

In the answer i put `def multi():

the answer i get is

> `[123, 4, 125, 69, 155] <class 'list'>`

and the correct answer is [161,131,129,75,4]

could anyone please point me in the right way?

Thank you.

Comment: Pointing right way: `num * 1` is not assigned to anything. `list1` is being returned without any changes (good part being that it's not modified while being iterated over, but why is it returned at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modify the for loop variable num itself and not the original list value
Code below should do the job

```
list1 = [123, 4, 125, 69, 155]
def multi():
    for i,num in enumerate(list1):
        if num % 2 == 0:
            num *= 1
        else:
            num += 6
        list1[i] = num # modify list value 
    return sorted(list1)[::-1] # this do sorting then reverse from large to small
```

Comment: [155, 125, 123, 69, 4]

Answer (score 0):

No need to multiply by 1. just check if number is odd add 6.

```
list1 = [123, 4, 125, 69, 155]
def multi():
    for i,num in enumerate(list1):
       if num % 2 != 0:
           num +=6 
       list1[i] = num
    return sorted(list1)[::-1]
```